# Was the continued urbanization of Coruscant ever protested?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, coruscant

From Wookieepedia:

> ...Meteorologically, the planet's weather patterns were affected by the troposphere-piercing buildings that covered the planet's surface...
>
> ...Thousands of years of urban development destroyed the planet's ancient mountains and seas. As such, Monument Plaza housed the top of Coruscant's last remaining mountain peak...
>
> ...citizens who lived in the upper levels were able to breathe air that was filtered and clean, while lower-class inhabitants were forced to breathe the air of toxic fumes from factory and vehicular waste. As such, most visitors to Coruscant chose to bring their own air supply to last the length of their stay...

With all these negative side-effects stemming from building an ecumenopolis, along with having to have all their food [shipped in](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142019/75000) and having that "clean" air [be cleaned artificially](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114525/75000), I would assume that at some point someone would be against any further development and destruction of the planet. While [not much is known](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143865/75000) of Coruscant's original ecosystem, there was enough that the planet's current state is vastly different from the original (ie not a desolate desert).

Obviously if they tried, they failed, **but has anyone ever attempted to save Coruscant's natural elements**?

Comment: Related, and full of good background info for anyone answering... http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143858/what-did-coruscants-nature-look-like-before-it-was-urbanized

Comment: Yes. They preserved [a mountain top](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Monument_Plaza). Children would come to visit it.

Comment: @Valorum I'd considered putting that in. Thanks for reminding me how serious people take responses on this site. Also, I'm at my vote limit for the day, so no points for you.

Answer (score 2):

Note: all of this is taken from the audiobook of *Catalyst: A Rogue One Novel*, so I can't include direct quotes like others who use book references.  If someone could add that, it would be greatly appreciated.

There is a section of Coruscant's western hemisphere, halfway between the pole and the equator, where there is undisturbed surface.

It was originally privately owned grassland, and left undeveloped because of complicated legalities.  It was later acquired by the Republic and it served as a refuge for some sentient space-cows (sentient ruminants) whose planet suffered a cataclysmic collision with a meteor.

However, the Empire evicted them, cited eminent domain, and it became a research area.

Comment: Did anyone complain?

Comment: Yes, because people used it as a recreation area, but then got used to the fact that it was a part of a renewable energy research area.

Comment: @Valorum if you have the book, this scene takes place at the beginning of chapter 15.

Comment: I've not read it (properly) yet. I was going to listen to it in audiobook format over the next few days.

Comment: Was there a named group involved in any protest? Or only the general population?

Comment: @SonOfSam No named group was mentioned in the book, just a bunch of citizens.